# This is Roblox Studio I am Wondering How To Make Leaderstats = Inf

Tags: lua, roblox

Im wondering how you make leaderstats = inf is it just for example

NumberValue = Inf or is it something else

D

Comment: Heyo Jdnator Gaming, it's very unclear what you're trying to do. Could you edit your question and elaborate the problem you're trying to solve? Have you tried any code yet? What issue have you run into? Are you looking for a place to start?

Comment: `NumberValue = math.huge`

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if that's what you're asking for.

math.huge is a number that is larger than any other numeric value.